# unterminated address regex on sed command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Im trying to write an XML tag in to a file. and i want that to be above another tag

**Script.sh**

```
sudo chmod 777 attribute-filter.xml
 configure_attribute_filter_tag1='<afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="uid">'
 configure_attribute_filter_tag12='</afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>'
  configure_attribute_filter_var='<afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="releaseTransientIdToAnyone">'
      sed -i '/'$configure_attribute_filter_var'/i \'"$configure_attribute_filter_tag1"'' attribute-filter.xml
     sed -i '/'$configure_attribute_filter_var'/i \'"$configure_attribute_filter_tag12"'' attribute-filter.xml
```

attribute-filter.xml

```
<afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="releaseTransientIdToAnyone">
    <afp:PolicyRequirementRule xsi:type="basic:ANY"/>

    <afp:AttributeRule attributeID="transientId">
        <afp:PermitValueRule xsi:type="basic:ANY"/>
    </afp:AttributeRule>

</afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    <afp:AttributeFilterPolicyGroup id="ShibbolethFilterPolicy"
                                    xmlns:afp="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp" xmlns:basic="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:basic" 
                                    xmlns:saml="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:saml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                                    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp classpath:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-afp.xsd
                                                        urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:basic classpath:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-afp-mf-basic.xsd
                                                        urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:saml classpath:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-afp-mf-saml.xsd">
   <afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="uid">
    </afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>

        <afp:AttributeFilterPolicy id="releaseTransientIdToAnyone">
            <afp:PolicyRequirementRule xsi:type="basic:ANY"/>

            <afp:AttributeRule attributeID="transientId">
                <afp:PermitValueRule xsi:type="basic:ANY"/>
            </afp:AttributeRule>

        </afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>
    </afp:AttributeFilterPolicyGroup>
```

**The Log when i execute script.sh**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated address regex
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated address regex
```

Can some one help me to identify the issue?

Comment: I am pretty sure you messed up with the ' in your sed statements.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the single quotes from your sed call:

```
sed -i "/$configure_attribute_filter_var/i $configure_attribute_filter_tag1" attribute-filter.xml
```

Your expected result includes the `afp:AttributeFilterPolicyGroup` element which is absent rom the `attribute_filter.xml` that you specify, i take it, that the actual file  contains said element.

Reconsider whether you really wish to transform a serialized tree structure with a line-oriented tool like sed.